# How the cell state size and cell output size is determined in BasicRNNCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Consider the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cell=tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units = rnn_size)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

According to the [documentation of dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), the `output` and `state` have shapes `[batch_size, max_time, cell.output_size]` and `[batch_size, cell.state_size]`, respectively.

The question: how the `cell.state_size` and `cell.output_size` is determined in `BasicRNNCell`? What is the relationship between `num_units = rnn_size` in the initilizer of BasicRNNCell and its `state_size` and `output_size`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of the `BasicRNNCell`, all the quantities you mentioned are the same (see [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) for reference):

```
 class BasicRNNCell(RNNCell):
     """The most basic RNN cell.

     Args:
      num_units: int, The number of units in the LSTM cell.
      activation: Nonlinearity to use.  Default: `tanh`.
      reuse: (optional) Python boolean describing whether to reuse variables

       in an existing scope.  If not `True`, and the existing scope already has
       the given variables, an error is raised.
     """

  def __init__(self, num_units, activation=None, reuse=None):
    super(BasicRNNCell, self).__init__(_reuse=reuse)
    self._num_units = num_units
    self._activation = activation or math_ops.tanh

  @property
  def state_size(self):
    return self._num_units

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return self._num_units
```